# Using YUI is it possible to add another css footer that sticks to the bottom of a page?

Tags: css, yui, footer, sticky-footer

I'm a big fan of using the YUI library as my CSS and design skills are typical of a developer. I can find many examples of  CSS techniques that result in a footer sticking to the base of a page. However I have failed in trying to add this to the YUI grids, I'm just wondering if anybody else has achieved this and if so would they mind sharing their approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: I pushed all the YUI content into <div id='main'> Added the css, changed the ids so they didn't clash with the yui one and viola!

Thanks for the link.